# He is in the same school as John or John's?

Tags: grammar, possessives, apostrophe

This is probably easy, but I'm confused right now and I was too clumsy to find an answer through Google. Which sentence is correct?

1. He is in the same school as John
2. He is in the same school as John's

Answer (score 1):

The first one is correct.

The second one means "He is in the same school as John's school," which is so clunky that I can't even figure out whether it's technically correct or not.

Comment: Alas, what you can and can't figure isn't dispositive.  They're both fine, either "He's in the same school as John [is in]" or "He's in the same school as John's [school]."

Comment: @deadrat: can you give an example of a normal-sounding sentence that uses the second construction? ?"He's in the same school as mine" sounds equally bad to me. Does it really sound fine to you?

Comment: @sumelic "Normal sounding"?  What's the definition of that?  But, I'll try.  How about "You hold an opinion that's not the same as mine"?

Comment: That's slightly different, though. There is no noun after the word "same." That sentence does sound acceptable to me, but something like ?"Do you hold the same opinion as mine?" is not acceptable in my judgement.

Comment: @deadrat: However, it does seem that "[the same opinion as mine](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=%22the+same+opinion+as+mine%22&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8)" is a phrase that's used in real life, and that is parallel in structure to "the same school as John's."

Comment: @sumelic isn't "John's" elliptical? "Maria's favourite bar is the same as Tony's/his (favourite bar)." Does that sound so strange to you?

Comment: @deadrat: I beg to differ. Not only is it dispositive; it is also definitive. As in "Rickius locuta est, causa finita est." Or hadn't you noticed.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: That's a slightly different grammatical environment, and I have no problem with it there. The noun phrase after "as" corresponds to the subject of the main verb (we could imagine that it is short for "Maria's favourite bar is the same as Tony's/his (favourite bar) [is]").

Comment: @deadrat: ["the same opinion as his"](https://books.google.com/books?id=Yo_nAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA16&lpg=PA16&dq=%22the+same+opinion+as+his%22&source=bl&ots=d8DPeB2CY-&sig=z2TORm11eWbz62GYvI1tvayADiU&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwin14TgnKvJAhUBTmMKHWD5AAkQ6AEIMzAJ#v=onepage&q=%22the%20same%20opinion%20as%20his%22&f=false) also sounded odd to me at first sight (weird mix of sensory expressions, I know).

Comment: "the same opinion as mine" is pretty rare (because it is clunky indeed) compared to "the same opinion as me", or occasionally "the same opinion as I". "He is in the same school as John" is correct, the other option is actually nonsensical.

Comment: @deadrat: I wonder if my confusion stems from the fact that in sentences like this, the "traditional" option is to use nominative form (which sounds really stilted in a lot of cases without a following verb) and the normal-register option I feel like I would use is plain-case form ("He has the same opinion as me"), so it's already hard for me to get reliable intuitions about grammaticality here. And now I have to think about a third option ("He has the same opinion as mine") that can be used to mean the same thing in the same context. I wish I knew what the history of each of these forms is.

Comment: @Cargill: so you would say "I know a lot of people with the same opinion **as me**" rather than ["I know a lot of people with the same opinion **as mine**"](https://whisper.sh/whisper/04f1165baa9642323394d977fd1ebbdaf398cb/I-know-a-lot-of-people-with-the-same-opinion-as-mine-Metal-has-gone-to), right? (Like I said, I think I would too.) But what's funny is that I don't even know if "I know a lot of people with the same opinion **as I**" would even be grammatical, since the (elided?) verb seems like it would have to be "have," which doesn't even occur in any earlier part of the sentence.

Comment: @sumelic: I did hesitate over "... same opinion as I" for the reasons you cite, but it ingrained to use "I" after "as" and "than", so it was included.